# Why is asm.js same speed or slower in this case?

Tags: javascript, firefox, asm.js

I was testing some asm.js compilation from the documentation [here](http://asmjs.org/spec/latest/#introduction). Based on their example, I tried this in Firefox 22:

```
function DiagModule(stdlib) {

    var sqrt = stdlib.Math.sqrt;

    function square(x) {
        x = +x;
        return +(x*x);
    }

    function diag(x, y) {
        x = +x;
        y = +y;
        return +sqrt(square(x) + square(y));
    }

    function many() {
        for (var i=0; i<2000000; i=(i+1)|0) {
            diag(+3000000-i,i);
        }
    }
    return { many:many };
}

var fast = DiagModule(window);

function testit() {
    console.time('test');
    console.log('diag test...');
    fast.many();
    console.timeEnd('test');
}
```

Oddly, there is no performance improvement when I enable compilation with "use js" on the line after "function DiagModule". In earlier testing it even ran slower. Does it have to be fully converted, using the heap instead of variables, to notice a speed difference? Or is there any documentation on where compilation of asm.js can be beneficial?

Comment: I assume you mean "use asm", not "use js"?

Comment: Didn't you forget  `"use asm";`?

Comment: Yes, I did "use asm". just mistyped that in the question.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. They apparently call the asm.js function from js many times, which I also tried, it made it ran about half as fast. Here I'm running the whole test in asm.js, I thought it would give a speedup converting the numeric portions.

Comment: "I thought it would give a speedup" is begging the question. Why make that assumption in the first place?